# Elasticsearch index with historical versions of documents

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch index continuously being updated and I'm creating a second index with the same mappings for doing offline analytics: I need to store changes for certain fields, in order to retrieve the values that were associated in specific time in the past. Therefore, in this second index I store multiple versions of the same document (same `id`  but different `_id` fields).

My objective is to get ranked results for a given query and reference date. I've tried with aggregations but rather than modifying the `hits` fields you get a new `aggregations` one with unordered results.

Is there any way other than removing duplicates at the client side?

This is similar but different to this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218309/can-we-retrieve-previous-source-docs-with-elastic-search-versions) as the proposed solution of just having a boolean `current` field allows for removing duplicates when querying the present.