# ES: save current doc into subfield as historic revision

Tags: elasticsearch, updates, elasticsearch-painless

I am trying to implement [store older versions within the same document](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8226684/41948) using `painless` scripting:

```
curl -XPOST http://127.1:9200/index1/type1/docid/_update -d \
{"script": {"inline": "ctx._source.previous.add(ctx._source)"}}
```

The response is

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [{
            "type": "remote_transport_exception",
            "reason": "[DJxHoBx][172.17.0.2:9300][indices:data/write/update[s]]"
        }],
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Object has already been built and is self-referencing itself"
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

So how can I make this work?

Comment: I think the URL needs to be `index1/type1/docid/_update`

Comment: @Val sorry for the typo. I edited.

Comment: And I think `ctx.source` should be `ctx._source`, right? You also probably need to remove the `ctx._source.previous` field in the older version you add into `previous`

Comment: @Val That's great insight! Now I need to find a way to subMap() or exclude a field in HashLinkedList for painless scripting.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by manually enumerate each keys:

`ctx._source['previous'].add({'x': ctx._source.x})`